# Validate more than one receipt at a time from Google developer API

Tags: google-api, in-app-subscription, auto-renewing

I have a react native app and using react-native-iap library to communicate with Google server to buy the subscriptions. I am using PHP to validate/auto-renewing status of receipt using Google's API i.e **[https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{{packageName}}/purchases/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/tokens/{{purchaseToken}}](https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/%7B%7BpackageName%7D%7D/purchases/subscriptions/%7B%7BsubscriptionId%7D%7D/tokens/%7B%7BpurchaseToken%7D%7D)**. But i am only able to check one subscriptions at a time. Is there any way to check auto-renew status of subscriptions in bulk rather than calling Google's API for each subscription/purchase token ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never heard of this.

What you can do though, is subscribe to real time notifications to know in real time the statuses of your subscriptions:

- https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready#configure-rtdn
- https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/rtdn-reference